# How to add repository to assembla (https) using SmartSVN

Tags: svn, repository, assembla, smartsvn

I am using SmartSVN in snow leopard. I am having trouble to add a repository to assembla. In assembla my svn url is like: "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/projectname/". I am using my gmail account for assembla.

Steps i did:

1. Add repository
2. I have click on enter svn url and then provide this url "https://subversion.assembla.com/svn/projectname/"
3. After that it looks like:[after pressing ok it looks like this](http://i39.tinypic.com/9ve4h2.png)
4. and then i continue and gave my username, password for gmail account. but every time it tells me to accept MD5 and SHA fingerprint. and then show me this error. [error image](http://i42.tinypic.com/xepd0m.png)

can anyone please tell me where i go wrong or where should i check. syncing through dropbox is not a good option :( or if you could give me a alternate solution(free to host) with how to integrate with that will also be ok.

thanks

Samin

Comment: Most likely the SVN username and definitely the password are different from your gmail account (assembla must not known about your gmail password!). Looks like you can set an SVN password in the sidebar of your profile: http://forum.assembla.com/forums/2/topics/2531-Subversion-authentication-fail

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems you signed up with OpenID and you have to set an Assembla password to use svn:

https://www.assembla.com/user/edit/edit_account_settings

PS: Do not enter your gmail password on other sites except google.

Comment: but what to enter into current password?